# How to assign a point label conditionally in ggplot2 scatterplot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I assign the points in my `ggplot` scatterplot a label like this, it works perfectly.

```
geom_text(aes(label=df[,c("name")])))
```

The problem is, however, that I aim to label only the "outstanding" dots, which happen to be those that have a `mycount` higher that say `500`. When I try to do this using the following snippet, the correct points are selected/labelled, but with a number (most probably the row index) instead of the `name`.

```
geom_text(aes(label=ifelse(df[,c("mycount")]>500,df[,c("name")],NA)))
```

Why does this not work and how should I modify the line so that points with a `mycount > 500` get labelled with their `name`?

Answer (score 3):

```
geom_text(data = filter(df, mycount>500),aes(label=name))
```

Should work

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work for me. Also, as stated in the question, I would love to understand WHY my above code does not work correctly.